# Accelerometer and trigger values

Tags: sensor, accelerometer, 6050

For my application I want a accelerometer to trigger on set threshold changing values. The application is attaching the accelerometer to a ball and turn-by-turn smash the ball into the ground, trying to "up the value" each time. So player1 will smash the ball light, causing 1G. Then the next player must smash the ball harder, maybe 1.2G. But the threshold then moves from 0, to 1 and to 1.2 and so on.

But I want to do this with interrupts so the connected MCU goes to sleep between smashes. I'm looking at MPU6050 but I'm unsure it its possible. If I did not make it sleep I could just measure the highest value at all times and have a method for setting it.

But this sensor does not support that if I understand the datasheet. I want the sensor to send interrupt when a threshold value is reached, but it only supports three types:

- FIFO_OFLOW_EN: I'm unsure of this. But if its data buffer is full it will send interrupt? Not useful.
- I2C_MST_INT_EN: As a I2C master it can be supported by other sensors, but that is not what I want.
- DATA_RDY_EN: When data is written to register this will fire. Not what I want. I want to be able to set "trigger on 3.2G" and "trigger on 2.1G" and so on.

Does anyone have experience with a accelerometer that supports interrupt and setting threshold values, or am I reading the datasheet wrong?

Datasheet: https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf
Register overview: https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Register-Map1.pdf

Comment: This is not documented in official docs, but can be found from different reverse-engineering folks, such as here: https://www.eluke.nl/2016/08/11/how-to-enable-motion-detection-interrupt-on-mpu6050/ . You probably can also find some libraries around utilizing the undocumented features and see how they do it.